# Null foreign key in database - but why?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database full of vehicles. Each vehicle can have many pictures. Obviously, the pictures table has a Vehicle foreign key.

Whenever I add a picture, then try to retrieve it, I cannot. This is due to the fact that the Vehicle foreign key is returned as Null. Trouble is, I don't understand why. At this point in time, understand that on a database level, all the fields in the picture table are populated as expected. There are 3 fields **`Id (PK, int)`**, **`Picture (nVarChar(max))`** and **`VehicleId(FK, int))`**. Crucially, **the foreign key (VehicleId) IS populated with a valid vehicle Id.**

I am using the MVC.

First of all, code for the Picture Model.

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Image {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("VehicleId")]
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle{get;set;}
}
```

Secondly, Picture Controller code that saves a picture. Notice how I am setting the Vehicle Foreign Key.

**IMPORTANT Clue** - If I put test code in Immediately before 'return Created' to retrieve a picture, I can. Vehicle Foreign Key appears to be set. If I just run the application and try to retrieve a picture straight away (i.e withoud adding a new one), the Vehicle Foreign key is null. Why though? I have included the code I call that retrieves an individual picture.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostNewPicture(int vehicleId_, PictureViewModel picture_)
{
    try
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var vehicle = _vehicleRepository.GetVehicleById(vehicleId_);
            if (vehicle == null) return BadRequest("Vehicle Not Found");

            var newPicture = _mapper.Map<Picture>(picture_);
            newPicture.Vehicle = vehicle;
            _vehicleRepository.AddPicture(newPicture);
            if (await _vehicleRepository.SaveChangesAsync())
            {
                var url = _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction("GetIndividualPicture", 
                                                        "Pictures",
                                                        new {vehicleId_ = newPicture.VehicleForeignKey.Id,
                                                             pictureId_ = newPicture.Id});
                var pictureViewModel = _mapper.Map<PictureViewModel>(newPicture);
                return Created(url, _mapper.Map<PictureViewModel>(newPicture)); 
            }
        }
        return BadRequest("Failed to save the picture");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest($"Exception Thrown :  {ex}");
    }
}
```

Code to retrieve an individual picture:

```
public Picture GetIndividualPicture(int vehicleId_, int pictureId_)
    {
        _vehicleContext.Pictures.Include(vp => vp.Vehicle);
        IEnumerable<Picture> pictures =  from v in _vehicleContext.Pictures.ToList()
                    .Where(x => x.Vehicle.Id == vehicleId_
                            && x.Id == pictureId_) select v;    
        return pictures.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Why VehicleForeignKey is Null, when it is clearly set at the point of adding?

Comment: Because you don't `Include` the `VehicleForeignKey` property in the latter query. In the `PostNewPicture` method the vehicle is attached to the context. BTW, dn't return `BadRequest` from an action method. The request itself succeeded if it made it to that point.

Comment: Sorry - not completely sure what you mean. By Latter query do you mean the query within 'GetIndividualPicture' (the second code listing)? If you do, what do you mean by not including the VehicleForeignKey property?

Comment: Yes the second code snippet. You don't have `_vehicleContext.VehiclePictures.Include(vp => vp.VehicleForeignKey)`. By the way, you really have to remove `ToList` there. It pulls the entire table into memory before filtering. Another side note, don't use names like `VehicleForeignKey`, just name it `Vehicle`.

Comment: Loving the  suggestions other than the answer. What is your reasoning for not naming VehicleForeignKey but Vehicle instead? As for the ToList removal - totally makes sense - Thanks!!

Comment: Common naming conventions. It's not a "VehicleForeignKey" you refer to, it's a Vehicle. In other classes a Vehicle could be a child entity. Even `_vehicleContext.VehiclePictures` is a misnomer IMO, I'd name it just `_vehicleContext.Pictures`.

Comment: naming conventions make sense - refactored accordingly. Thanks! Still having an issue with the null foreign key though even after the Include. About to update the original article. Maybe you could be so kind as to cast your eye over it quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to Gert Arnold for this one. He correctly states
the second code snippet. You don't have _vehicleContext.VehiclePictures.Include(vp => vp.VehicleForeignKey)

I feel like a bit of a fraud answering this myself - again, It was Gert. Here are my check in notes on this....

12th November 2019
    Pictures Controller - I could not understand why the foreign Key withing the Pictures
    table was always being returned as null. The answer was because I was not Including it.
See Include in the query below. Dont include this and Vehicle is always null.
    ALSO - I was using .ToList() immediately after the .Include(vp => vp.Vehicle)
    dont do this - it loads the entire result set into memory BEFORE  any filtering is done

```
    public Picture GetIndividualPicture(int vehicleId_, int pictureId_)
        {
            IEnumerable<Picture> pictures =  from v in _vehicleContext.Pictures
                        .Include(vp => vp.Vehicle)
                        .Where(x => x.Vehicle.Id == vehicleId_
                                && x.Id == pictureId_) select v;    
            return pictures.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```